# consecutive XHR calls failed silently, Not sure about the reason.

Tags: angular, webpack, aws-lambda, okta, zone.js

following is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "angular-io-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Example project from an angular.io guide.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start karma.webpack.conf.js",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --bail",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.0",
    "@okta/okta-signin-widget": "1.7.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.6.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

i am using okta login and also added `canActivate` at

`imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterModule.forRoot([
    {//route configs
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/cfbsetup',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'login', 
      component: OktaComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'cfbsetup', 
      component: CFBSetupComponent,
      canActivate:[AuthGuard]
    },`

further `canActivate` function in `AuthGuard` service is

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Promise<boolean> {
    let componentThis:AuthGuard = this;
    let mypromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        componentThis.oktaService.isAuthenticated().then((e:any) => { 
           if (e) { 
               resolve (true); 
           } else { 
               componentThis.router.navigate(['/login']);
               resolve(false); 
            }
        });
    });

Now login redirects page to Okta login page which checks for active session `isAuthenticated():any {
    let componentThis:any=this;
    var mypromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      componentThis.oktaSignIn.session.get((response:any) => {
      if (response.status !== 'INACTIVE') {
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
      })
    });
    return mypromise
  };
```

`

after that if authenticated my default route get loaded correctly but i am calling my data from AWS Lambda

```
getResponse(fnName:string, payload: any) :any {

    let response:any;

    AWS.config.update({region: this.config.IdentityPoolRegion});
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId: this.config.IdentityPoolId});

    let lambda: any= new AWS.Lambda({region: this.config.LambdaRegion, apiVersion: this.config.apiVersion});
    let lambdaSettings: any = {
            FunctionName : this.config.FunctionName,
            InvocationType : "RequestResponse",
            LogType : "None",
            Payload : JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    var mypromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        lambda.invoke(lambdaSettings, function(error:any, data:any) {

            if (error) {
                 reject(response = error);
            } else {
                resolve(response = JSON.parse(data.Payload));
                console.log("response in service",response);
            }
        });
    });
    return mypromise;
};
```

when i deactivate login by removing `canActivate:[AuthGuard]` from route i get data correctly from lambda function but with okta login call my call to Lambda fails silently no error and nothing

i checked Network tab in chrome i suspect zone.js is initiator for both XHR calls, after okta session call aws lambda call fails. not sure though but is it something related to websocket ? as i noticed an call `http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/info?t` before okta call

i checked all promises working fine, checked with few different versions of zone.js, didnt find anything..

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

I think your AuthGuard service needs some work. The method signature for `canActive` should return a boolean, not a boolean wrapped in a Promise. For example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

From: http://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/04/17/angular-authentication-with-oidc#create-open-id-connect-app

Answer (score 0):

changed zone.js's version

```
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

its working for now..